# Is there a way to tell what kind of tag I hit when parsing XML in Android?

Tags: android, xml, parsing, tags, sax

Looking at this website for the correct tag taxonomy:
http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xmltag.php

Is it possible to tell if I'm grabbing attributes from tag pair vs a solo tag?  If it helps I'm currently using a SAXParser.

Comment: Oh dear. Tizag, possibly even worse then W3Schools, and that is saying something.

Comment: Why do you care if it is a start tag or an empty element tag? You'll need to treat `<foo />` and `<foo></foo>` identically anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SAXParser you can't recognize about that as I know.
XMLPullParser can recognize that.